# Devise route issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using devise for authentication on my project.  I created a basic controller called panel with rails.  When I am at the home url the link works as it should. But for some reason the link_to in my layout file attempts to find a route that does not exist when I go to /users/sign_in, the default login for devise.

In my layout file I have this link that should always be shown.

```
   <%= link_to "Panel", :controller => "panel", :action => "index" %>
```

when I attempt to access the default user login path on devise /users/sign_in it gives the error:  ActionController::RoutingError in Devise/sessions#new

No route matches {:controller=>"devise/panel"} from the layout file.

routes:

```
  get "panel/index"

  get "home/index"

  devise_for :users
```

It looks like the routes go into some sort of devise scope when I click on the link for the users/sign_in path.

Comment: Could you please include your routes?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`routes.rb`:

```
get "panel/index" => 'panel#index', :as => 'panel'
```

In your controller:

```
<%= link_to "Panel", panel_path %>
```

Comment: That does not work unfortunately.                                     No route matches {:controller=>"devise/panel"}

Answer (score 0):

```
 get "panel/index", :as => :panel_index


 <%= link_to "Panel", panel_index_path %> |
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing the following also solves it,

```
    <%= link_to "Panel", :controller => "/panel", :action => "index" %>
```

Source: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/471